# Rails4 + PDFKit + Fonts + Heroku not working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, fonts, pdfkit

I'am trying to solve a font issue on heroku using PDFkit since few days and nothing seem to work for me....

I've already did few solutions such as :
Convert LucidaHW from Squirrel and do as follow ...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lucida_handwritingitalic';
    src: url(data:application/x....
```

or this solution with .font on that website:  http://www.mobalean.com/blog/2011/08/02/pdf-generation-and-heroku

or using :

```
kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root.join("public","stylesheets", "pdf", "pdf.css.scss")}"
```

I also moved my pdf.css.scss into vendor folder, into public folder and nothing ...

Right now, i am a bit confused because almost all of it work in dev mode (on my localhost) but nothing on heroku.
I'am aware this is not the first ticket about that issue but nobody found a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue a few months back.
This is what I'm doing right now and it has been working great for me:

1.Serve assets in base64:

add this helper method:

```
def asset_data_base64(path)
  asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(path)
  throw "Could not find asset '#{path}'" if asset.nil?

  base64 = Base64.encode64(asset.to_s).gsub(/\s+/, "")
  "data:#{asset.content_type};base64,#{Rack::Utils.escape(base64)}"
end
```

and in your template, include assets like this: (the example uses haml)

```
  = stylesheet_link_tag(asset_data_base64('pdf/pdf.css'))
  = javascript_include_tag(asset_data_base64('pdf/pdf.js'))
```

2.custom fonts

move all your fonts to a folder in your project. (I put mine under `vendor/assets/fonts`) then add a new initializer file in your `config/initializers`

```
if Rails.env.production?
  font_dir = File.join(Dir.home, ".fonts")
  Dir.mkdir(font_dir) unless Dir.exists?(font_dir)

  Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","fonts", "*")).each do |font|
    target = File.join(font_dir, File.basename(font))
    File.symlink(font, target) unless File.exists?(target)
  end
end
```

replace `Rails.root.join("vendor","assets","fonts", "*")` withe the path to the folder where you put all your font files.

then in your css, do not use font-face, use the font name directly, e.g. `font-family: Gotham;`

Also, do not user fallback fonts! In some versions of wkhtmltopdf, it always uses the fallback font if one is provided.

=============================================

1. I learned the base64 trick from here: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/257
2. Custom fonts solution was found here: http://www.mobalean.com/blog/2011/08/02/pdf-generation-and-heroku

Comment: Thx for your answer. I'am gonna give this a try !

Comment: Hi sorry for my late answer. The first step seem to work fine but i have issue to link font. If i have a file lucidahw-webfont.ttf, then how should i call it in the pdf.css ?

Comment: Also i did connect on heroku run bash and i do not see any .fonts folder created by the initializer. Considering that you link fonts with file basename it must be why it's not working ?

Comment: It depends on the name of the font...try open the font file with a font editor/viewer and see what it is called. Also, when you run bash, it doesn't initialize the rails application - thus the initializers are not executed.

Comment: Yuri Ray Zhang, you made my day ;)
Works great (finaly) !

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the font in a `.fonts` folder in you app root and push it to Heroku - just refer to the font via the font family and not with a src. That's how I use custom fonts on Heroku with wkhtmltopdf and it works for me.

Comment: Hi, thx for answering. If i add lucidaHW.ttf in Rails.root/.fonts i just call it with font-family: 'lucidaHW' ? Cause right now its not working :/